# Bootstrap: Съезжают div'ы

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Здравствуйте. Начал верстку на bootstrap и столкнулся с проблемой. Необходимо сделать вывод новостей в 2 колонки, построчно. Блоки с новостью имеет разную высоту. Проблема заключается в том что блоки съезжают под блоки которые выше имеют меньшею высоту.

```
div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9">
    <span class="col-sm-6"><h3><a href="#">Совет директоров Facebook, работавший в 2013 году, может лишиться зарплаты из-за неправильной подписи Цукерберга</a></h3><h5>Слишком поздно. И подпись все еще стоит на другом, неправильном бланке. Суд Делавэра решил, что Цукерберг не использовал необходимый метод выражения согласия акционера, поэтому согласие не берется в расчет.</h5><h6 class="pull-right">15.11.15 22:29 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i>355 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></i>12</h6></span>
    <span class="col-sm-6"><h3><a href="#">Совет директоров Facebook, работавший в 2013 году, может лишиться зарплаты из-за неправильной подписи Цукерберга</a></h3><h5>Если вы находитесь на самых высоких позициях в корпорациях, если у вас нет руководителя, кто решает, сколько вам будут платить? Для вас это не проблема. Вы сами решаете, сколько будете получать. Будьте щедрыми! Но это проблема для того босса, которого у вас нет: директора корпораций работают с акционерами, которые не всегда контролируют происходящее в компаниях. Директора выбирают себе зарплату, и некоторые акционеры начинают волноваться из-за того, что она слишком высокая.</h5><h6 class="pull-right">15.11.15 22:29 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i>355 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></i>12</h6></span>
    <span class="col-sm-6"><h3><a href="#">Совет директоров Facebook, работавший в 2013 году, может лишиться зарплаты из-за неправильной подписи Цукерберга</a></h3><h5>Вот что произошло в Facebook. В его совете директоров восемь человек. Из них шесть не являются сотрудниками компании. Еще двое — главный операционный директор Шерил Сэндберг, а также Марк Цукерберг, сооснователь, гендиректор и председатель совета директоров. Еще Цукерберг считается мажоритарным акционером компании — он владеет 15% акций, при этом контролирует 60% голосующих акций.</h5><h6 class="pull-right">15.11.15 22:29 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i>355 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></i>12</h6></span>
    </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Решение средствами самого bootstap, без изменения css. Если у вас такая верстка на всех разрешениях можно добавить "перевод строки".
После двух блоков пустой `<div>` c классом clearfix

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Если у вас такая верстка, что вы хотите чтобы этот перенос был не на всех расширениях, то можно дополнительно задать видимость этого пустого div-а:

```
<div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
```

**PS** Измените в вашем примере span на div. У вас блочные элементы, span же используют в случае строчных элементов, так для вашего примера лучше подходит div.

**PSS** Верстать обычный текст и мелкие элементы заголовочными тегами `<h5>` и `<h6>` тоже неправильно

То есть итоговый код должен быть таким (неправильное использование h5 и h6 исправьте сами):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div class="col-sm-6"><h3><a href="#">Совет директоров Facebook, работавший в 2013 году, может лишиться зарплаты из-за неправильной подписи Цукерберга</a></h3><h5>Слишком поздно. И подпись все еще стоит на другом, неправильном бланке. Суд Делавэра решил, что Цукерберг не использовал необходимый метод выражения согласия акционера, поэтому согласие не берется в расчет.</h5><h6 class="pull-right">15.11.15 22:29 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i>355 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></i>12</h6></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6"><h3><a href="#">Совет директоров Facebook, работавший в 2013 году, может лишиться зарплаты из-за неправильной подписи Цукерберга</a></h3><h5>Если вы находитесь на самых высоких позициях в корпорациях, если у вас нет руководителя, кто решает, сколько вам будут платить? Для вас это не проблема. Вы сами решаете, сколько будете получать. Будьте щедрыми! Но это проблема для того босса, которого у вас нет: директора корпораций работают с акционерами, которые не всегда контролируют происходящее в компаниях. Директора выбирают себе зарплату, и некоторые акционеры начинают волноваться из-за того, что она слишком высокая.</h5><h6 class="pull-right">15.11.15 22:29 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i>355 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></i>12</h6></div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6"><h3><a href="#">Совет директоров Facebook, работавший в 2013 году, может лишиться зарплаты из-за неправильной подписи Цукерберга</a></h3><h5>Вот что произошло в Facebook. В его совете директоров восемь человек. Из них шесть не являются сотрудниками компании. Еще двое — главный операционный директор Шерил Сэндберг, а также Марк Цукерберг, сооснователь, гендиректор и председатель совета директоров. Еще Цукерберг считается мажоритарным акционером компании — он владеет 15% акций, при этом контролирует 60% голосующих акций.</h5><h6 class="pull-right">15.11.15 22:29 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i>355 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></i>12</h6></div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.row {
    font-size:0; // обнуляем значение font-size
}
.row > div {
    font-size: Npx; // Восстанавливаем значение font-size "по умолчанию"
    float: none!important;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

**update**

Автор, у вас `HTML` не верный.
Каждая последовательность `col-` должна иметь в родителях `.row`

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="row">
            <span class="col-sm-6"><h3><a href="#">Совет директоров Facebook, работавший в 2013 году, может лишиться зарплаты из-за неправильной подписи Цукерберга</a></h3><h5>Слишком поздно. И подпись все еще стоит на другом, неправильном бланке. Суд Делавэра решил, что Цукерберг не использовал необходимый метод выражения согласия акционера, поэтому согласие не берется в расчет.</h5><h6 class="pull-right">15.11.15 22:29 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i>355 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></i>12</h6></span>
            <span class="col-sm-6"><h3><a href="#">Совет директоров Facebook, работавший в 2013 году, может лишиться зарплаты из-за неправильной подписи Цукерберга</a></h3><h5>Если вы находитесь на самых высоких позициях в корпорациях, если у вас нет руководителя, кто решает, сколько вам будут платить? Для вас это не проблема. Вы сами решаете, сколько будете получать. Будьте щедрыми! Но это проблема для того босса, которого у вас нет: директора корпораций работают с акционерами, которые не всегда контролируют происходящее в компаниях. Директора выбирают себе зарплату, и некоторые акционеры начинают волноваться из-за того, что она слишком высокая.</h5><h6 class="pull-right">15.11.15 22:29 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i>355 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></i>12</h6></span>
            <span class="col-sm-6"><h3><a href="#">Совет директоров Facebook, работавший в 2013 году, может лишиться зарплаты из-за неправильной подписи Цукерберга</a></h3><h5>Вот что произошло в Facebook. В его совете директоров восемь человек. Из них шесть не являются сотрудниками компании. Еще двое — главный операционный директор Шерил Сэндберг, а также Марк Цукерберг, сооснователь, гендиректор и председатель совета директоров. Еще Цукерберг считается мажоритарным акционером компании — он владеет 15% акций, при этом контролирует 60% голосующих акций.</h5><h6 class="pull-right">15.11.15 22:29 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i>355 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></i>12</h6></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Так же, крайне рекомендую `<span class="col-sm-6">` превратить в `<div class="col-sm-6">` по многим соображениям

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы так не происходило нужно помнить что в одной строке 12 колонк, если вам нужно 50% то нужно было написать

Нормальный вариант
    
       
          ...
          ...

```
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-6'>...</div>
      <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-6'>...</div>
    </div>
```

Вариант воспользоваться костылем как написано выше
вставить 
после двух дивов col-md-6

Answer (score 0):

Делаем дочерние элементы col-xs-6 одинаковой высоты

```css
.row-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-flex">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam tincidunt sagittis augue et luctus. Donec in nunc lacinia, imperdiet turpis ac, rutrum ligula. Curabitur in purus dui. Quisque dapibus tortor nulla, sed sodales tellus dictum sit amet.
        Nam sit amet placerat orci, non tincidunt velit. Nullam rutrum diam a massa faucibus condimentum. In auctor pretium ex et elementum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam tincidunt sagittis augue et luctus. Donec in nunc lacinia, imperdiet turpis ac, rutrum ligula. Curabitur in purus dui. Quisque dapibus tortor nulla, sed sodales tellus dictum sit amet.
        Nam sit amet placerat orci, non tincidunt velit. Nullam rutrum diam a massa faucibus condimentum. In auctor pretium ex et elementum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam tincidunt sagittis augue et luctus. Donec in nunc lacinia, imperdiet turpis ac, rutrum ligula. Curabitur in purus dui. Quisque dapibus tortor nulla, sed sodales tellus dictum sit amet.
        Nam sit amet placerat orci, non tincidunt velit. Nullam rutrum diam a massa faucibus condimentum. In auctor pretium ex et elementum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam tincidunt sagittis augue et luctus. Donec in nunc lacinia, imperdiet turpis ac, rutrum ligula. Curabitur in purus dui. Quisque dapibus tortor nulla, sed sodales tellus dictum sit amet.
        Nam sit amet placerat orci, non tincidunt velit. Nullam rutrum diam a massa faucibus condimentum. In auctor pretium ex et elementum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam tincidunt sagittis augue et luctus. Donec in nunc lacinia, imperdiet turpis ac, rutrum ligula. Curabitur in purus dui. Quisque dapibus tortor nulla, sed sodales tellus dictum sit amet.
        Nam sit amet placerat orci, non tincidunt velit. Nullam rutrum diam a massa faucibus condimentum. In auctor pretium ex et elementum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam tincidunt sagittis augue et luctus. Donec in nunc lacinia, imperdiet turpis ac, rutrum ligula. Curabitur in purus dui. Quisque dapibus tortor nulla, sed sodales tellus dictum sit amet.
        Nam sit amet placerat orci, non tincidunt velit. Nullam rutrum diam a massa faucibus condimentum. In auctor pretium ex et elementum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam tincidunt sagittis augue et luctus. Donec in nunc lacinia, imperdiet turpis ac, rutrum ligula. Curabitur in purus dui. Quisque dapibus tortor nulla, sed sodales tellus dictum sit amet.
        Nam sit amet placerat orci, non tincidunt velit. Nullam rutrum diam a massa faucibus condimentum. In auctor pretium ex et elementum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam tincidunt sagittis augue et luctus. Donec in nunc lacinia, imperdiet turpis ac, rutrum ligula. Curabitur in purus dui. Quisque dapibus tortor nulla, sed sodales tellus dictum sit amet.
        Nam sit amet placerat orci, non tincidunt velit. Nullam rutrum diam a massa faucibus condimentum. In auctor pretium ex et elementum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam tincidunt sagittis augue et luctus. Donec in nunc lacinia, imperdiet turpis ac, rutrum ligula. Curabitur in purus dui. Quisque dapibus tortor nulla, sed sodales tellus dictum sit amet.
        Nam sit amet placerat orci, non tincidunt velit. Nullam rutrum diam a massa faucibus condimentum. In auctor pretium ex et elementum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam tincidunt sagittis augue et luctus. Donec in nunc lacinia, imperdiet turpis ac, rutrum ligula. Curabitur in purus dui. Quisque dapibus tortor nulla, sed sodales tellus dictum sit amet.
        Nam sit amet placerat orci, non tincidunt velit. Nullam rutrum diam a massa faucibus condimentum. In auctor pretium ex et elementum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam tincidunt sagittis augue et luctus. Donec in nunc lacinia, imperdiet turpis ac, rutrum ligula. Curabitur in purus dui. Quisque dapibus tortor nulla, sed sodales tellus dictum sit amet.
        Nam sit amet placerat orci, non tincidunt velit. Nullam rutrum diam a massa faucibus condimentum. In auctor pretium ex et elementum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.row div{
    width: 49%!important;
    float: none!important;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: ну что это за 49%?! то что будет криво по дизайну пофигу чтоли?